# Getting error The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign when I followed their tutorial

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm using windows, xampp and fairly new on integrating docusign. [I watched this tutorial from docusign using PHP](https://youtu.be/OBBiKjDPRgo), however since the tutorial is using mac, I'm getting confused on how I will setup this tutorial on my xampp and windows and the result is I'm getting the error:

> The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign

Here is how I did my setup

1.) Clone the repository and place it on my `xamp/htdocs/eg-something-something`

2.) Rename the ugly repository name to `xamp/htdocs/docusign/`

3.) Run composer install to get the dependencies

4.) I configured my **ds_config.php** and here is my code... I removed credentials for security purposes

```
<?php
// ds_config.py
// 
// DocuSign configuration settings

$DS_CONFIG = [
    'ds_client_id' => 'xxxx', # The app's DocuSign integration key
    'ds_client_secret' => 'xxx', # The app's DocuSign integration key's secret
    'signer_email' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
    'signer_name' => 'Michael',
    'app_url' => 'http://localhost/docusign/public', // The url of the application.
    // Ie, the user enters  app_url in their browser to bring up the app's home page
    // Eg http://localhost/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/public if the app is installed in a
    // development directory that is accessible via web server.
    // NOTE => You must add a Redirect URI of app_url/index.php?page=ds_callback to your Integration Key.
    'authorization_server' => 'https://account-d.docusign.com',
    'session_secret' => '{SESSION_SECRET}', // Secret for encrypting session cookie content
    'allow_silent_authentication' => true, // a user can be silently authenticated if they have an
    // active login session on another tab of the same browser
    'target_account_id' => false, // Set if you want a specific DocuSign AccountId, If false, the user's default account will be used.
    'demo_doc_path' => 'demo_documents',
    'doc_docx' => 'World_Wide_Corp_Battle_Plan_Trafalgar.docx',
    'doc_pdf' =>  'World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf',
    // Payment gateway information is optional
    'gateway_account_id' => '{DS_PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ID}',
    'gateway_name' => "stripe",
    'gateway_display_name' => "Stripe",
    'github_example_url' => 'https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/tree/master/src/',
    'documentation' => false
];

$GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG'] = $DS_CONFIG;
```

5.) I log into my admin sandbox and use this as my redirect URI

```
http://localhost/docusign/public/index.php?page=ds_callback
```

The web app is running but I am having an error of  **"The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign"** when I click the login or just by authenticating.

Thanks for helping me on this issue.

**Update part:** 
I tried adding http:// on the configuration of the integration key on sandbox, however, I'm getting a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL
>   error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile:
>   C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\docusign\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php
>   on line 186

Once I tried to authenticate. [Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cm0z.jpg) for the errors.

Comment: So, have you registered the redirect URL with DocuSign (the service as well, not just in your config)?

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson, Yes, I login to my sandbox, clicked my Integrated Key and added this value on the redirect URI (http://localhost/docusign/public/index.php?page=ds_callback) and I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

try `http://localhost/docusign/public/index.php?page=ds_callback` as the redirect URL.

You need the complete URL including the http:// part.

Comment: I tried to add http:// part and now I am receive an error that I have no idea how to fix Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\xampp\htdocs\docusign\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186.